# Use LINQ to filter files based on separate given extension array

Tags: c#, linq

I am working on .NET CORE 6 solution. I have list of files along with each extension and another list of extensions i.e. .csv. I want to LINQ to filter files from list 1 based on list 2. i.e. if list 2 have .csv & .txt then LINQ should filter out only .csv and .txt files. I did implement solution but it is using loop

```
  private List<string> FilterFilesWithAcceptedExtenison(List<string> files, List<string> acceptedExtensions)
    {
        List<string> FilteredFiles = new List<string>();

        foreach(var file in files)
        {
            var extension = Path.GetExtension(file);

            if (acceptedExtensions.Contains(extension))
            {
                FilteredFiles.Add(file);
            }
        }

        return FilteredFiles;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) clause to filter `files` based on given criteria. Like,

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...
List<string> FilteredFiles = files
     .Where(file => acceptedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file))
     .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

its simply

```
var filteredFiles = files.Where(f => acceptedExtensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f)));
```

You can throw a `ToList()` on the end if you *really* need it to be a `List<string>`.